# Response code indication while using Modbus RTU

Tags: c#, serial-communication, modbus

I am using Modbus RTU protocol to read data. I have Slave Id = 1 and Modbus Address = 40023. I am configuring Start Address = 22. **Is it correct with my Modbus Address?**

If I am configuring following details:

> Slave Id= 1 Baud Rate = 19200 Stop Bits = 2 Data Bits = 8 Parity =
>   None Start Address = 22

I am reading data with following code

```
var master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);
ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, 1);  //2 is number of points
```

With these details I am getting this response in console:
**INFO Modbus.IO.ModbusSerialTransport - TX: 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 184, 68**

In above response I only know some of them what they indicate like first digit 1 indicate Slave Id, 3 indicate function Code, 22 indicate Start Address, 2 indicate number of points.

Can anyone please explain me remaining code? What they indicate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start address is encoded in two bytes (0, 22). Number of registers is also encoded in two bytes (0, 2). (37, 207) is the CRC, needed in all Modbus RTU frames.

Comment: Start Address I have configured is right? How to get / read value?  Are we making the correct request for reading value from holding registrar?

Comment: The request is correct. Can you post the response from the slave?

Comment: Here is the response: 1 3 0 22 0 1 101 206. Please note number of count I have passed now is 1

Comment: Are you sure this is what you got from the slave? It seems like a request, where you changed the number of registers to 1 and the CRC changed as expected.

Comment: Yes, with Slave Id = 1, Start Address = 22 and number of point = 1 & I have passed all three parameters to this function: ReadHoldingRegisters() &  I got this response: 1 3 0 22 0 1 101 206
Is this a correct response? Because as per the documentation I referred, if function code is same in response then response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your console text is a request package.

Its meaning is in the image below

[image]

Comment: This is my response in console: 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 184, 68. What is the data in this response?

Comment: <pre>
Part of Data Package    Description           Value
01                      Slave address         0x01 (1)
03                      Function code         0x03 (3) - Read Holding Registers
02                      Byte count            0x02 (2)
00 00                   Register value        0x0000 (0)
B8 44                   CRC                   0xB844 (47172)
</pre>
 You can do the same by yourself using the online tool [http://modbus.rapidscada.net/](http://modbus.rapidscada.net/)